# Layout and Drawable folder for 8inch Tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, tablet

I've been researching SO and [this blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.ie/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html) in relation to creating correct layout folders for tablet design.  I'm working on an application which will support larger phones and tablet 7/8/10 inch.  All the research points to a layout folder of  layout-sw600dp for 7inch and layout-sw720dp for 10inch.  Am I right in understanding that the layout-sw600dp will cover anything from 7inch up to 10inch and then layout-sw720dp for 10inch +?  Also my drawables are as follows hdpi/mdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi I'm assuming that that these remain and no additional folders are required for tablets?  Any infor would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use : "drawable-sw720dp" for 10'' tablets, containing 720px-width images" for the 8" Tablet .

For more info you can refer here , as 8" is reside between 7-10 Range so that you can use 10" drawable folder

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I have been looking at the docs thank you, it's just not very clear to me.  So I have images for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhpdi, do I need further images for the tablets?  Also do I need to add something to the manifest to support screens?

Comment: Please use drawable-sw600dp

Comment: hi, thanks for that, I'm talking about additional images?  Do I require additional images for that folder?  Also, it may not just be an 8 inch tablet that will be used, from 7 to 10

Comment: addition images from the url or gallery ?

Comment: images to drawable-sw600dp , layouts to layout-sw600dp you can add

Comment: I understand that.  At the moment, the project is set up with drawable-mdpi/drawable-hdpi/drawable-xhdpi/drawable-xxhdpi.  My concern is what drawable files to put into drawable sw-600dp?

Comment: Just add new folder android will automatically detect.

Comment: add an empty folder called drawable sw-600dp and leave it empty?  Why add the folder if it has no contents?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70841/discussion-between-dj-doo-and-vatsal-shah).

Comment: Sorry chat is not enable for me.

Comment: ok, here is the problem I have: If I  add an empty folder called drawable sw-600dp  what drawables do I put in it? Why add the folder if it has no contents?
I have drawables designed by a designer suitable for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhpi. So if I add an additional drawable folder called drawable-sw600dp what drawables do I put in that folder?

Comment: You have to say designer to design for 8 inch tablet too and after it extract please put in this folder.

Comment: really?  At the moment, it's taking images from the xhdpi folder.  If that was the case the designer would need to design for 5, 7, 8 and 10 inch folders as well as mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi...that can't be correct\

Comment: Yes because the resolution of the tablet of 8" near 720*1280 so it will take from near by folder for that resolutions.

Comment: so I require 8 sets of drawables?

Comment: Yes you have to add this drawable folder